# Ctrl-Shift-P opens font dialog in Word 2010 instead of focusing on font size in toolbar

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

In older versions of MS Word (2000, 2003, etc) using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> would focus on (highlight) the font size box in the toolbar allowing me to change the font size.

In newer versions (2010) it instead opens the font dialog to have me select a font size.

While it's not overly inconvenient, is there a way to revert it to the old behavior where I can just modify the size without having a window come up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Word 2010 **does** say that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is assigned to **Font Size**:

[image: screenshot]

But this now opens the **Font** window. *How intrusive!*

[image: font]

To replicate the old functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, you have to first press <kbd>Alt</kbd>...

[image: alt]

then <kbd>H</kbd>...

[image: h]

and finally, <kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd>.

That's a lot of work! So, I wrote an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) script to *fix* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Word
^+p::
KeyWait, Ctrl
KeyWait, Shift
Send, {Alt}hfs
Exit
```

If you are unfamiliar with AutoHotkey, I've compiled the script for you. Just run it and it will stay in the system tray (**Right click** > **Exit** to close it).

---

**Download:** [http://ahk.igalvez.net/MSWord2010Fontsize.exe, 784 KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/MSWord2010Fontsize.exe)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that Microsoft removed the shortcut ,    all that  you now have to do is **highlight** the word and the popup for adjusting font and style comes up.
Personally I think that its more user friendly.

P.S-

A lot of shortcuts have changed in the new versions, head over to this [link](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Word_2010.html) to check some of the shortcuts available.

Edit-
Changed Windows to Microsoft

Comment: he may not want to change it for a highlighted word. but just change it for text he'll type after changing it

Comment: Also, highlighting the word with the keyboard (shift/ctrl+arrow) does not bring up the **mini toolbar**.

Comment: Shortcuts are set in applications not in OS. Windows could not have change a shortcut for Office.

Comment: meant microsoft :|